# Binding dropdown list selected value from controller side in @Html.DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What's the correct way to bind the selected value to dropdown list generated using @Html.DropDownList from controller. i.e. selection of dropdown should occur from controller side. This how I have generated the dropdown.

`@Html.DropDownList("CountryFilter", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Coutries, "Select", new { id = "CountryFilter" })`

My approch -
I tried updating the value using jquery by using id selector but I was unable to receive the value to be selected from  controller in OnPageload method like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        $('#RoleFilter').val(@ViewBag.roleFilter.ToString());
    });
```

It worked when I hardcoded the value like this

`$('#RoleFilter').val("3");`

But I was unable to get the value from ViewBag.

My issue can be resolved in two ways

1. Using Jquery
2. Binding value to the dropdown directly.

Comment: Use console.log to what is there instead of the value.

Comment: I tried using console.log when page is loaded the line becomes $('#RoleFilter').val(''). THE @..... Values are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your code worked when you hardcoded the value, then must try the below code for getting value in ViewBag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     $('#RoleFilter').val(@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.roleFilter.ToString())); //Accessing the Json Object from ViewBag
  });
```